# Where can I find macrofun.hlp?

Tags: programming, application-program, documentation, microsoft

In the days before Visual Basic for Applications, the macro language for Microsoft Excel was called XLL. The syntax was similar to that of ordinary Excel formulas, except for two things:

- Macros were executed cell by cell until a `=RETURN()` or `=HALT()` statement.
- XLL functions could have side-effects, like loading DLLs (`REGISTER`).

XLL has a documentation file called "macrofun.hlp", the presence of which in the correct location would reenable the XLL wizard until at least Excel 97. Trouble is, Microsoft have [taken the downloads down](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=9253) and [removed the online reference](https://support.microsoft.com/kb/128185).

Is macrofun.hlp still available? How can I find it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The help file is still available [elsewhere on Microsoft’s site](http://download.microsoft.com/download/excel97win/utility4/1/win98/en-us/macrofun.exe). The `macrofun.exe` file there is a self-extracting cabinet file containing `macrofun.hlp`, the table of contents (`macrofun.cnt`) and a README file with usage and installation instructions.

Comment: And it's no the least bit of fun, even if the name implies so... ;)

Answer (score 4):

Here is the direct link to the ressource:
http://download.microsoft.com/download/excel97win/utility4/1/win98/en-us/macrofun.exe

It still works as of today.